# Dual Representation and Dual Vector Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-transformations, vector-bundles, dual-spaces

The lecture notes I used in my differential geometry class defined attaching to $P$ the fiber $V$ (w.r.t $P$) as follows:

> We define the vector bundle obtained by attaching to $P$ the fiber $V$
> (w.r.t. $\rho$ ) as the resulting quotient $$ E(P, V)=E(P, V,\rho):=(P \times V) / G=\{[p, g]: p \in P, v \in V\} $$ where $[p, v]$
> denotes the element in the quotient represented by $(p, v) \in P
>  \times G$ (so that, in $E(P, V),[p g, v]=$ $[p, g v]$ for all $p \in
> P, v \in V, g \in G)$. Further, we endow $E(P, V)$ with the projection
> $$ \pi_E: E(P, V) \rightarrow M, \pi_E(p, v)=\pi_P(v) . $$ and the
> fibers will be the vector spaces: $$ E(P, V)_x=\left\{[p, v]: p \in
>  P_x, v \in V\right\}, \quad[p, v]+[p, w]=[p, v+w] $$
> In this general framework, the representation $\rho$ encodes a linear action of $G$ on $V$ from the left,
> $$
> G \times V \rightarrow V, \quad(g, v) \mapsto g \cdot v:=\rho(g)(v),
> $$
> which, combined with the right action of $G$ on $P$, induces a (right) action of $G$ on $P \times V$ :
> $$
> (p, v) \cdot g:=\left(p g, g^{-1} v\right)
> $$

Edit:
When I try to apply this to $Fr(E) \times_{\rho} V^*$, where $\rho : GL_r \to GL_r(V) : A\to (A^{-1})^t$. This is quite confusing. This space is supposed to be isomorphic to $E^*$, which means that $$[e_x\cdot A, v^*] \sim [e_x, (A^{-1})^t v^*]$$ and they should give rise to the same linear functional in $E^*_x$. Note that $v^* : V \to \mathbb{R}$. With identification $E_x \simeq_f V$ (which is not canonical (?), choose the basis as $e_x$ ) Then $v^* \circ f : E_x \to \mathbb{R}$. How do I show that $$[e_x\cdot A, v^*] \sim [e_x, (A^{-1})^t v^*]$$ give rise to the same linear functional in $E^*_x$ ?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Your notation $e_x\cdot A$ implies that $e_x$ is an element of the fibre of $P$ over $x$, and thus can be identified with an element of $G=\text{GL}(V)$. Then you talk about an inner product, even though there's no such thing without explicitly specifying one. Unless you mean the dual pairing. But in either case, such a pairing is between the vector $v^*$ and another vector. And $e_x$ is not a vector. So what do you actually mean?

Comment: $e_x = (e_1,..,e_r)$ is a frame such that when viewed as a linear map it maps $\mathbb{R}^r $ to $E_x$. $v^* \in V^*$ is a dual vector. Identify $E_x$ with $V$, then $E_x \cong V \to_{v^* }\mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional. I am trying to check whether the same element in theequivalence class gives the same linear functional.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The dual pairing is between $v^*$ and $e_i (1 \leq i \leq r)$

Comment: Okay, that's a good start. Next question: you noted correctly that the dual representation is given by $A\mapsto (A^{-1})^t$. Where did the inverse go in the desired relation $[e_x\cdot A, v^*]\sim[e_x,A^tv^*]$?

Comment: I guess they are in the same equivalence class because changing the basis in $E_x$  by matrix $A$ is equivalent to changing the basis on the dual space by $(A^{-1})^t$ ?

Comment: Yes that's right. This is why the dual representation is defined in the way that it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149638/discussion-between-z-y-h-and-quaere-verum).